# How to find path trough blocks in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm

I've got a grid 9x9 squares. Those squares are written in array of integer.
so every integer represents 1 block. Integer provides enough bits for X,Y positions, if this block is accessible and other data. I have a problem: What would be the most effective way to get boolean value, if we can get from the center of this grid to some random point. So for example i provide X and Y positions for block where i want to go, and a method will return boolean value, if there is some way through ACCESSIBLE blocks. I made a simple picture for this. Thanks for answers.[image: Can i get from blue to green trough white]

Comment: Have you even tried to search for this problem? It is a standard problem and there exist numerous algorithms for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing here is a well-known problem in computer science called [pathfinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) and not trivial to solve efficiently.

However, there are several algorithms to solve this, like [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which are probably the way to go for large, complicated maps.

If all of your problems are as small and simple as your posted example, you could also try to work with a simpler solution, like a brute force graph search, ([as suggested by Codor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32869363/1090166)).

Comment: You're right, the picture makes clear that the path is required, although the description more demands a test whether the starting point and some given point lie in the same connected component.

Comment: Ah yeah, that would simplify the problem a bit.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach in this case ti doesn't seem the graph will be weighted thus I think DFS or BFS would do the job just fine

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), where the specific implementation greatly depends on the representation of the grid, which is to be interpreted as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).